# How to crawl from a website which has load more button?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

As you can see, this website (https://www.vanglaini.org/tualchhung) has a **load more button**.

[image: LoadMore]

How to crawl it till the end? It crawls till the first few news in my code.

Here is my existing code

```
source = requests.get('https://www.vanglaini.org/tualchhung').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

list_with_headlines = []
list_with_summaries = []
list_with_links = []

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    if article.a is None:
        continue
    headline = article.a.text.strip()
    link = "https://www.vanglaini.org" + article.a['href']
    list_with_headlines.append(headline)
    list_with_links.append(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'lxml')
    list_with_summaries.append(soup.select_one(".pagesContent").text)

news_csv = pd.DataFrame({
    'Headline': list_with_headlines,
    'Summary': list_with_summaries,
    'Link' : list_with_links,
})

print(news_csv)
news_csv.to_csv('1.csv')
```

Comment: Load more is a form, you can use `requests` library to keep submitting the form and get the contents

Comment: What have you done to try to resolve this? This is a topic that comes up regularly on Stack Overflow, and for which there should be a large amount of resources available.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot ask the website to load the full site using just request and python. I used selenium to mimic a real user, load JS and then scrape the website. Here is the code when you use selenium. Hope it helps.

```
script = '''
         function getElementByXpath(path) {
                return document.evaluate(path, document, null, 
                XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
             }
         var load_more = getElementByXpath("//*[@id='previousDayForm']/input[3]");
         load_more.click();
         '''
time.sleep(1) //wait till the page load - can be done using JS as well    
driver.execute_script(script)
time.sleep(1) // wait till the load-more button fetched the content. Increase decrease second according to your internet speed
```